# No working time showing Js when close webpage

Tags: javascript, time

```
pageOpen = new Date();

function bye() {
    pageClose = new Date();
    minutes = (pageClose.getMinutes() - pageOpen.getMinutes());
    seconds = (pageClose.getSeconds() - pageOpen.getSeconds());
    time = (seconds + (minutes * 60));
    if (time == 1) {
        time = (time + " second");
    } else {
        time = (time + " seconds");
    }
    alert('you stay here' + time + '.welcome back!');
}
```

Call it with

```
<BODY onUnload="bye()" >
```

When I try to close it, but nothing showing.

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: Where are you calling it?

Comment: Either Pop Up Blocker or Chrome just ignoring code onunload to make the page faster. Code works fine when called via a timeout.

Comment: so how do I change it? or noway to do it?

Comment: Chrome console: "Blocked alert('you stay here1 second.welcome back!') during unload."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unload event does not work on all browsers. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp
(notably not on chrome or opera)

If you want to show a message to confirm or leave a page like some pages do when you have unsaved changes - you can always use the beforeunload event

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
pageOpen = new Date();

function bye() {
    pageClose = new Date();
    minutes = (pageClose.getMinutes() - pageOpen.getMinutes());
    seconds = (pageClose.getSeconds() - pageOpen.getSeconds());
    time = (seconds + (minutes * 60));
    if (time == 1) {
        time = (time + " second");
    } else {
        time = (time + " seconds");
    }
    return ('you stay here' + time + '.welcome back!');
}
</script>
</head>

<body onbeforeunload="return bye()">

<h1>Welcome to my Home Page</h1>
<p>Close this window or press F5 to reload the page.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And do you know how to add minutes and hours when pop-up?

Comment: @user3089026 I don't understand your question - Can you give me an example of what the popup message should look like?

Comment: Right now, the code only show the seconds on the alert, I want it with minutes and hours.

Answer (score 0):

the format of unload is:

```
<body onunload="myFunction()">
```

Comment: put the alert to first line of your bye() function.. debug you know!!

Comment: Browsers do not case about the case when it is an attribute, they normalize it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$( window ).unload(bye);
```

hope this help)

Comment: Where is the jQuery tag? -1

Comment: Not everyone uses jQuery